# Calculate the linking number of two loops in $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Given two loops $t\mapsto (sin(t),cos(t),sin(t+\phi),cos(t+\phi))$ and $t\mapsto (sin(t),cos(t),sin(t),cos(t))$ for $\phi\in]0,2\pi[$. How to show that their linking number is one?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: @anon I'll change the title.

Comment: I guess you could try Gauss's integral definition! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Gauss's_integral_definition

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip thanks for the link. But since here the space is $S^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$, I don't know how to use this definition.

Comment: You can use the fact that $S^3\cong(\mathbb{R}^3)^+$ is the 1-point compactification. Essentially use stereographic coordinates to project from $S^3-\{p\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $p$ is some point not in the image of the loops. Then follow Gauss.

Comment: @Tyrone I have thought about that. But I don't know how to prove that the linking number doesn't change if we remove a point from the space, the same way that a loop in the plane becomes incontractible if we remove an interior point?

Comment: You're not actually removing a point. Just using the chart to perform the calculation.

Comment: A possible mistake: these loops lie on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{2}$.  You need to normalize or make it clear what you mean by $S^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking number is a continuous function of $a$, and it is undefined whenever the two loops intersect.  Notice that the two loops intersect only when they are the same loop, when $\phi=2\pi n$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, on your domain for $\phi$, linking number is constant.

Now, let's pick a convenient value for $\phi$ to calculate the linking number.  Probably right in the middle of the domain will work well: $\phi=\pi$.

Like I mentioned in a comment, the paths you have are not normalized to lie on the unit sphere, but they become normalized by dividing by $\sqrt{2}$.

It is not too hard to come up with an orthogonal matrix that carries the path $h(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),0,0)$ to the second path.  Here is one:
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Then, $A(0,0,\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is the first path at $\phi=\pi$.  Thus, the problem comes down to finding the linking number between $t\mapsto (\cos(t),\sin(t),0,0)$ and $t\mapsto (0,0,\cos(t),\sin(t))$.

I find it easiest to contemplate linking number in a stereographic projection.  I will make the odd choice of projecting from $(0,0,0,1)$, odd since the second of the loops passes through it.  Projected, the paths are $t\mapsto (\cos(t),\sin(t),0)$ and $t\mapsto (0,0,\frac{\cos(t)}{1-\sin(t)})$.

Notice that the first loop wraps around the $z$ axis counter-clockwise once, and the second loop *is* the $z$ axis.  There is a single singularity at $t=\pi/2$, so this loop travels along the $z$ axis in the positive direction and passes through $\infty$ once.  This is enough to know that the linking number is $+1$.